# How to make water pour in GML?

Tags: game-maker, gml

How can I make water pour from a flask in game maker where  have `obj_flask` , `obj_water` , and `obj_container`.
I want to make the `obj_water` pour from `obj_flask` into the `obj_container`.

Answer (score 0):

This depends hugely on how you want to achieve this effect. You could for example have an animated sprite stretching from the flask to the container. Or you could create water droplet instances at a given time rate and let them be affected by gravity. Or you could use a particle system, but this usually gives you less control if you want to check if it actually hit the container.

I can show you how to make the second idea to get you started.

**obj_jug**

```
Step Event:

execute code:

x = mouse_x;
y = mouse_y;
if (mouse_check_button(mb_left))
{
    instance_create(x + 32, y + 8, obj_droplet);
}
```

**obj_droplet**

```
Create Event:

execute code:

a = 1;
v = 0;

Step Event:

execute code:

v += a;
y += v;
if (y >= window_get_height())
{
   instance_destroy();
}

Collision Event with object obj_container:

destroy the instance
```

This will not give a great effect, but it will do what is being asked.