# How to pour liquid in game maker?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I want to put water sprite inside the flask and when i drag it on top of the container it pour this water into the container.
Does anybody know how to do this in game maker?
And here is a picture of the flask and container [image: Flask and container in game maker room]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make water pour in GML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067422/how-to-make-water-pour-in-gml)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rectangle that is only visible through the sprites of the recipients and change it's scale when you pour it. For example, link it's image_yscale variable to the quantity of poured liquid.

If you are motivated, shaders could be the solution. Otherwise, you could simply design flat-bottomed recipients, make them transparent, and use the draw event to draw a liquid-colored rectangle inside of them before drawing them. The result won't be as astonishing, but far easier.

your draw event could look like ;

1 - draw the rectangle at the x & y coordinates (you may have to use an offset), with the correct scale using image_xscale & image_yscale, and the correct angle which is the flask's image_angle variable.

2 - draw the recipient after that.